# Implement System.Data.Common DbConnection with WPF C#

Tags: wpf

I am trying to use the abstract class DbConnection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=netframework-4.8).

The reason why I want to use the class is because I am going to write a program where the user can choose between diffrent database types.

I have written a class named DBAdapter that implemtns DbConnection. However I cannot connect to any database with it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace DatabaseSQLiteAndPostgreSQLWPF.dao
{
    class DBAdapter : DbConnection
    {
        public DbConnection dbConnection;

        String databasePath = ""; //  SQLite only (appData + "\\" + projectName + "\\" + "db")
        String databaseFile = ""; //  SQLite only (mydb.db)
        String databaseType = ""; //  new Database(DatabaseType.MySQL);
        String databaseHost = ""; // localhost
        String databasePort = ""; // 5432
        String databaseUser = ""; // root
        String databasePassword = ""; // 
        String databaseName = ""; // csharp


        /*- Constructor ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        public DBAdapter(String dbType, String dbPath, String dbFile,  String dbHost, String dbPort, String dbUser, String dbPassword, String dbName)
        {
            // Assign variables
            this.databaseType = dbType;
            this.databasePath = dbPath;
            this.databaseFile = dbFile;
            this.databaseHost = dbHost;
            this.databasePort = dbPort;
            this.databaseUser = dbUser;
            this.databasePassword = dbPassword;
            this.databaseName = dbName;

            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + databaseHost + ";" + "DATABASE=" + databaseName + ";" + 
                "UID=" + databaseUser + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + databasePassword + ";";
            dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        } // Constructor



        public override string ConnectionString { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override string Database => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override string DataSource => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override string ServerVersion => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override ConnectionState State => throw new NotImplementedException();
        protected override DbTransaction BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /*- Open ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        public override void Open()
        {
            this.dbConnection.Open();
        }

        /*- Close --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        public override void Close()
        {
            this.dbConnection.Close();
        }

        public override void ChangeDatabase(string databaseName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override DbCommand CreateDbCommand()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```